# Selectively sample raster pixels

Tags: r, raster, sample

I have a large raster and I want to pick a bunch of pixels from them (say every 500th pixel). Doing this since I must make sure that the selected pixels are at least 5 km away from each other (the raster resolution is 250 x 250 sq. m). Picking every 500th pixel in the context of my work helps me solve this problem.

What I did to get the required pixels is to just convert the raster into an xyz table and then pick every 500th row from the xyz table. The thing is, since the raster is super large, the conversion to the xyz table takes ages. Is there any faster way to do this?

EDIT: For the conversion to the xyz table, I used the rastertoPoints function of course.

Comment: have you checked the `raster` package?. or you're already using it?

Comment: @ManuelF yes. I did. Random sampling seems to be quite easy. However, that is not what I need.